# Are Web Operating Systems practical yet?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, user-interface, web-operating-system

I'm a full time web developer but I have my roots as a desktop programmer and there seams to be a lot of talk about Web Operating System these days.

Is it practical yet to incorporate your web applications into a Web OS to make it more user friendly or just do a traditional HTML layout?

I found one that looks very interesting which is based on Ext JS and PHP that seams it will be simple for me to incorporate my own web applications into and make them feel more like a desktop app.

qWikiOffice - http://qwikioffice.com/

http://glidertools.net/preferences.jpg

Comment: the tag webos is inappropriate here (as also outlined by salt.racer below). webOS is the operating system that runs the palm pre.

Comment: @bismuth - Keep in mind that this question was asked before the Pre was announced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow me to be the first to say that a "WebOS" is a bit of a misnomer. What is really meant is a web "application" that looks and feels like a modern operating system because it has folders and other widgets.

I think that for some things a "webos" will eventually be practical, but for now, a "traditional" html layout that incorporates traditional desktop application type concepts via AJAX is the current level of practical.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, did you mean "practical"?  Or "piratical"?

Anyway, yeah, I think they're practical for a certain class of users.  not great for developers, very good for people who want lightweight apps and a way to read RSS and search/surf the web.

Comment: Please explain what you mean about "piratical". ;))

Answer (score 2):

Though the idea is cool it is not practical because of the fact that a lot of countries in the world have miserable internet speeds. I have just been to Thailand, most places the internet was not fast enough for gmail to work in ajax mode. It could take up in western countries.

Answer (score 2):

More answers here:
[Web Desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398044/web-desktops-do-you-find-it-interesting)

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to see a compelling reason to use a WebOS.  My browser has tabs and I really do not mind having all my Web Applications opened in different tabs.  My OS is mostly used for file manipulation which I would never want to do in a Web Browser anyways.

I see these as nothing more than people playing with a lot of JavaScript.  If you are going to develop a web app why not make it so the most people will be able to use it (keep it off a specific WebOS).